# Why can an unauthorized user have full access to an smb share they have no permissions on?

Tags: permissions, samba

The 'clients' user whom is only supposed to have access to the 'backups' share has full write access to the 'data' share. Why is this?

(Shares are all at bottom of paste)

/etc/samba/smb.conf: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6258594/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the lines at 346 and 361 where they have 'user' is incorrect.

These should be replaced with 'valid users'

Upon doing this and restarting the smbd service, everything as far as credentials worked as expected.